# K2 Items under K2 Category

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

Basically I have the following K2 hierarchy:

```
- Category CARS
-- Sub Category Audi
--- Item Audi A3
--- Item Audi A5
-- Sub Category BMW
--- Item BMW 120d
--- Item BMW M5
```

I wanted to display those K2 Items in that order, but it seems that by default K2 displays like the following:

```
- Category CARS
-- Sub Category Audi
-- Sub Category BMW
--- Item Audi A3
--- Item Audi A5
--- Item BMW 120d
--- Item BMW M5
```

I have my menu item displaying `k2 > Category CARS`. Everything is fine but not the displaying order.

How can I achieve the desired order?

Best regards

Comment: Why you can show audi items In bmw category? Did you write your question right?

Comment: @Max I did write my question right. The second example is the K2 default display. Not the way I want though.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this in your Admin config:

Menu >> Item Menu K2 Category >>
Tab Options >>

1. Fetch items... (Will show children items in yours subcategories)
2. Item Ordering ... (You can choose may options)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For any setting related to K2 there is just no simple answer. It is very powerfull and hence pretty tough beast to tame.

K2 Category blog view has three distinctive areas:
1. Root category block with it's title, image, description
2. Sub-categories block, with their titles, images and descriptions
3. Items block, with items belonging to either root category and/or sub-categories, with their atributes. Items display depends on settings chosen in both main category and sub-categories.

But there is no setting which will enable you to mix blocks 2 and 3, which is what you want, if I understand your question correctly.

Only way I can see your problem might be solved is to create specific K2 category view layout override, but that might turn out to be pretty messy. I for one would have to scratch my head pretty hard to achieve it.